# Can I find a plane in $\mathbb P^3$ to which a foliation $\mathscr F \subset T\mathbb P^3$ is tangent on a smooth curve?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, foliations, holomorphic-foliations

In this question, we work over an unspecified algebraically closed field, not necessarily of characteristic zero.

Let $\mathscr F$ be the $1$-dimensional foliation of $\mathbb P^3$ defined by the polynomial vector field

$$\mathscr F : P \frac \partial {\partial x} + Q \frac \partial {\partial y} + R \frac \partial {\partial z}$$

away from the plane at infinity $L \cong \mathbb P^2$. Assuming $L$ is not $\mathscr F$-invariant, which is the case for a generically chosen plane,  then $P, Q, R$ are of the form

$$P = xC + F, \qquad Q = yC + G, \qquad R = zC + H,$$

where $C$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $d$, and $F, G, H$ are arbitrary polynomials of degree $\le d$. The number $d \in \mathbb N$ is called the degree of the foliation. Geometrically, $C$ is the locus of points where $\mathscr F$ is tangent to $L$.

For reasons that can be seen in my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4023528/4675), I would like $C$ to be a smooth curve. The foliation $\mathscr F$ is fixed, but I am allowed to perform a linear change of coordinates of $\mathbb P^3$, which basically amounts to selecting a different plane at infinity. Can I always find a plane $L \subset \mathbb P^2$ that is not $\mathscr F$-invariant, and such that the curve $C$ where $\mathscr F$ is tangent to $L$ is smooth?

Comment: You are using $H$ in your second paragraph to denote both the plane at infinity and a polynomial of of higher degree (in the definition of $R$).

Comment: @TabesBridges: Oops, sorry! Thanks for noticing.